# Does my garden brickwork need mortar?

Tags: landscaping

We recently redesigned the walkway through our garden to our back door. This involved lots of scaping of the land -- especially to change the waterflow away from the house. The new walkway ends with a small brick landing. The contractor just laid them down and glued them in place.

I asked when they would finish it with mortar or sand or something. they said they they were set tight enough and didn't need it.

Except when I step on it they move. And I live in Minnesota -- wont snow and ice get in there? 
Am I missing or something or will this landscaping element not hold up?

Comment: What did the bricks get laid onto eg Sub-base material, concrete slab? Can you please expand on "glued them in place"? Could you please post a photo of the area? If possible could you also please give more details on exactly what the contractor did? Regardless, those bricks should not move when you step on them...

Comment: They were placed with some type of adhesive onto a sub-base material -- a concrete slab that was there. I don't know more than that -- I was at work when the contractors were working. What should I be asking or challenging them on? I will post pictures Mike -- but I am fairly confident that they will be super non-informative and boring.

Comment: @JosephBarisonzi I like photos :) Plus it could prove helpful to see the area, might make possible suggestions more meaningful to your particular situation. For starters ask them to explain why newly laid bricks are moving underfoot when you step on them, as there is no reason I can think of why properly installed bricks should behave like that (IMHO).

Comment: I don't want to provide an answer here because the people at DIY will definitely be more primed and experienced to answer this kind of question (there has been discussion about dropping the "landscaping" part of the G&L title since it's generally ignored anyway)... but I'm pretty sure you should sweep crusher dust (not sure what this is called outside Australia) into the cracks so they pavers/bricks stay firmly in place.

Comment: In Minnesota, brick walkway should *not* be cemented in with mortar. The 120ºF annual temperature variation causes trouble. Providing excellent drainage and allowing the individual bricks to move slightly is best. A *flexible* adhesive might be a new approach to this issue. I am not sure.

Comment: **Note to all:** This question has been [cross-posted on DIY](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8960/) and has been very well received there and has a good answer fom "the man" himself. I know that there hasn't been much interest in landscaping questions (especially hard landscaping ones) and as per [this meta discussion](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/36/where-are-the-boundaries-on-topic-vs-off-topic/249#249), such questions are better suited to DIY. However, I'd like to give these a chance here. So I'm interested in hearing your thoughts (continued...)

Comment: (contd... 2/2) Please voice your opinion in the meta post linked to above. If you feel such questions are better suited to DIY, please vote to close as off-topic (The question has already been answered there, so as far as this Q goes, the OP will not be affected). Alternately, you can also post an even more kick-ass answer here :)

Comment: I will speak up! I think you want your community to be as inviting as possible and encouraging. Interpret scope from the perspective of intention. If the asker is asking in good faith because they are seeking information -- keep it open, edit it to polish it, and encourage participation.

Comment: @JosephBarisonzi Your question is still open, and I actually did say _"I'd like to give these a chance here"_... I was merely soliciting community participation in the meta question. I'd also appreciate if you could drop by our chat sometime :)

Comment: Why did someone choose to vote this question down? I honor the ability to anonymously downvote a question -- but, what would be the reason here? Thanks!

Comment: AU."crusher dust" ==  US."stone dust".  And I concur - it should be swept between the bricks.

Answer (score 4):

I live in a climate similar to Minnesota and have never seen commercial landscapers gluing hard pavers down.
 - you say "brick", most brick will flake and spall after a few seasons because it is only hardened to the elements on one side.
 - Even interlock, which is cement, does not perform well in the long run when it is constantly moist.  These are the conditions that are found when you have a non porous bed of cement with bricks on top that allow water through the cracks.
 - The only places that I use adhesive on natural stone or on interlock is for cap stones on walls and treads for steps.  In each case you must supply adequate drainage through the use of permeable materials behind the wall or under the base of the step such as a bed of 3/8" gravel.
 - If there are gaps in the bricks I recommend you add [polymeric sand](http://www.groundtradesxchange.com/pavers/polymeric_sand.htm).  In the past I would never pay $25 for a bag of sand but this material is superb for filling joints, stays permeable and does not wash out.